# Executing Python NAOqi SDK

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, naoqi, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to figure out how to run ROS on the Nao. I've tried using ROS Hydro and the Nao Python SDK (although had little luck) so I installed ROS Fuerte and am trying to follow the instructions provided by the ROS wiki.

At one point it says to check the installation by executing naoqi:
$ ~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux32/naoqi

This does not work, even when I replace naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux32 with my corresponding version (pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64). My question is: how do I execute naoqi? Is there some command that I should be typing into the command line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172876/executing-python-naoqi-sdk/) by [ROSwithNao](https://answers.ros.org/users/18795/roswithnao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials have been totally revamped here: http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2015-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0